# Self-test suite fails on Unexpected character

Tags: sonos

I have problems sending request via the Self-Test Suite. I receive

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected character '2' (code 50) (expected a name start character)
```

It seems to be caused by the zonePlayerId

```
<tns:credentials>
     <tns:zonePlayerId>
        <tns:255/>
     </tns:zonePlayerId>
     <tns:deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:Z</tns:deviceId>
     ...
```

In the wsdl it's

```
<xs:element name="credentials">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="zonePlayerId" type="tns:id" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="deviceId" type="tns:id" minOccurs="0"/>
```

It should be the same as the device id. Sending via soapUi I have no problems because there is no extra tns.

```
<ns:credentials>
     <ns:zonePlayerId>255</ns:zonePlayerId>
     <ns:deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:Z</ns:deviceId>
```

Did you change something?
I was able to run them last time and we would like to submit a new version asap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the self-test and we are working to get a fix out soon. I will update this thread once we have published an updated self-test.

Thank you,
Jessica

Comment: The updated self-test, with the fix for the above issue, is now live on the Sonos Labs site.